# Why a tag "deutsch-als-fremdsprache"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Some questions were tagged with:

[deutsch-als-fremdsprache](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deutsch-als-fremdsprache)

Do we really need this tag to further classify a question? What additional value would be added from this tag?

In case we decide we need this tag we should translate it to English as we had discussed to have tags in one language (English) only. German tags will then be synonymized to the corresponding English tag. What would then be a sensible English name for this tag?

**The tag is now removed from all question to make it disappear over time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*German-as-foreignlanguage*?

No, we don't need it at all. Any kind of question should address a particular issue and the tag should indicate the kind of issue. But being non-native is not a helpful information here (Not to mention, that we're able to tell whether someone is native German or not, anyways).

Comment: Correct English would be “German as a foreign language”.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how this tag has been used in the past, but it might be useful for questions that address teaching German as a foreign language.